# Корректная запись jquery объекта в localStorage -?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Записываю в `localStorage` объект `JQ` - тобишь реальный элемент на странице.

Делаю это так:

```
localStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify($('.object')));
```

Теперь нужно получить это и использовать. Вопрос как?

пытался разными способами это сделать:

```
var test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'));
var test = $(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object')));
```

Но ничего их этого не работает. подскажите как быть?

**EDIT#1** - Если записать просто в объект `JS` - `currObject.value = $('.object')`, то всё работает как нужно.

Comment: А для чего это, собственно, нужно? Что именно нужно запомнить?

Comment: @AleksG сам объект JQ. что бы после извлечь и использовать его.

Comment: Сам объект JQ прицеплен к конкретно загруженному документу.  Если его записать, а потом считать в другой раз, в нем будет мусор, так как документ, скорее всего, поменялся. Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить? Наверняка, записывать JQ - не то, что нужно.

Comment: что такое "объект jQuery"? Это обертка вокруг элемента[-ов] DOM, существующего[-их] в контексте текущей страницы. Сериализовать их в localStorage - бессмысленно. "Объясните, чего Вы хотите" - Корней Чуковский "У меня зазвонил телефон".

Comment: @AleksG Открываю модальное окно, записываю $('.modal') в localStorage. При закрытии считываю его с localStorage.

Comment: @Tsyklop - как Вы (судя по Вашему коду) понимаете, localStorage может хранить только строки. Объект jQuery содержит ссылки на DOM-элементы страницы. Даже если предположить, что это корректно сериализуется в строку для записи в localStorage, десериализовать эту строку обратно в ссылки на те же самые DOM-элементы - невозможно. Храните в localStorage что-то другое, например - строку-селектор, или обходитесь без localStorage.

Comment: Побуду кэпом/телепатом: если надо сохранить содержимое модального окна, то надо html-код с помощью того же jquery и достать

Answer (score 0):

В хранилище имеет смысл хранить только данные, ссылки на объекты хранить бессмысленно, ибо:

> Ссылка в программировании — это объект, указывающий на определенные
>   данные, но **не хранящий** их.

<sub>[Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).</sub>

Пример вызова `JSON.stringify(jQuery('div'))` на этой странице:

```
{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{},"7":{},"8":{},"9":{},"10":{},"11":{},"12":{},"13":{},"14":{},"15":{},"16":{},"17":{},"18":{},"19":{},"20":{},"21":{},"22":{},"23":{},"24":{},"25":{},"26":{},"27":{},"28":{},"29":{"sizcache03947042977355806":128,"sizset":0},"30":{},"31":{},"32":{},"33":{},"34":{},"35":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":46,"sizcache03947042977355806":128,"sizset":0},"36":{"sizcache03947042977355806":128,"sizset":0},"37":{},"38":{"sizcache03947042977355806":128,"sizset":0},"39":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":11,"sizcache03947042977355806":128,"sizset":0},"40":{},"41":{},"42":{},"43":{},"44":{},"45":{"sizcache03947042977355806":128,"sizset":0},"46":{},"47":{},"48":{"sizcache03947042977355806":128,"sizset":0},"49":{},"50":{},"51":{},"52":{},"53":{},"54":{},"55":{},"56":{},"57":{},"58":{},"59":{},"60":{},"61":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":12},"62":{},"63":{},"64":{},"65":{},"66":{},"67":{},"68":{},"69":{},"70":{"sizcache03947042977355806":97,"sizset":0},"71":{},"72":{},"73":{},"74":{},"75":{},"76":{},"77":{},"78":{},"79":{},"80":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":48},"81":{},"82":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":101},"83":{},"84":{},"85":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":49},"86":{},"87":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":95},"88":{},"89":{},"90":{},"91":{},"92":{},"93":{},"94":{},"95":{},"96":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":43},"97":{},"98":{},"99":{},"100":{},"101":{},"102":{},"103":{},"104":{},"105":{},"106":{},"107":{},"108":{},"109":{},"110":{},"111":{},"112":{},"113":{},"114":{},"115":{},"116":{},"117":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":44},"118":{},"119":{},"120":{},"121":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":45},"122":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":17},"123":{},"124":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":18},"125":{},"126":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":19},"127":{},"128":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":20},"129":{},"130":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":21},"131":{},"132":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":22},"133":{},"134":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":23},"135":{},"136":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":24},"137":{},"138":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":25},"139":{},"140":{"jQuery17107429453865053492":26},"141":{},"142":{},"143":{},"144":{},"145":{},"146":{},"147":{},"148":{},"149":{},"150":{},"151":{},"length":152,"prevObject":{"0":{"location":{"hash":"","search":"","pathname":"/questions/559449/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-jquery-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-localstorage","port":"","hostname":"ru.stackoverflow.com","host":"ru.stackoverflow.com","protocol":"http:","origin":"http://ru.stackoverflow.com","href":"http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559449/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-jquery-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-localstorage","ancestorOrigins":{}},"jQuery17107429453865053492":2},"context":{"location":{"hash":"","search":"","pathname":"/questions/559449/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-jquery-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-localstorage","port":"","hostname":"ru.stackoverflow.com","host":"ru.stackoverflow.com","protocol":"http:","origin":"http://ru.stackoverflow.com","href":"http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559449/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-jquery-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-localstorage","ancestorOrigins":{}},"jQuery17107429453865053492":2},"length":1},"context":{"location":{"hash":"","search":"","pathname":"/questions/559449/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-jquery-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-localstorage","port":"","hostname":"ru.stackoverflow.com","host":"ru.stackoverflow.com","protocol":"http:","origin":"http://ru.stackoverflow.com","href":"http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559449/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-jquery-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-localstorage","ancestorOrigins":{}},"jQuery17107429453865053492":2},"selector":"div"}
```

Привязка к, возможно, уникальному кэшу; объекты, которые содержат лишь похожие свойства с DOM-элементами; бессмысленность их хранения, когда проще их найти по... CSS-селектору, например.
Всё это говорит о том, что Вы хотите закрутить лампочку гвоздодёром.